# Python: Efficiently sample an n-dimensional distribution from density array

Tags: python, numpy, resampling, self-organizing-maps

I have a N-dimensional distribution for which I have estimated the Gauissian kernel density that I have stored as an N-dimensional array. I need to perform a 2D Kohonen map fitting to the underlying distribution.

The simplest way of doing it in Python I found so far would be to use the `newc` module from [neurolab](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newc.html).

However, this module requires a cloud or points and I would need to sample the N-dimensional array to recover the points that would correspond to my original density distribution.

What would be the most efficient way to perform such sampling? Alternatively, are there any Kohonen map modules that would work directly with the density arrays?